# String comparing between output system command with defined variable

Tags: python

I tried to compare the output of command line with a variable that's already defined
but the logic always throw FALSE instead of TRUE.

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial | awk '{print $3}'
6RA3X34P
```

In Python:

```
hdserial="6RA3X34P"
cmd1="sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep Serial | awk '{print $3}'"

output = subprocess.check_output(cmd1, shell=True)

def check_serial(string):
    if string != hdserial:
        print '\nQuitting..'
        sys.exit()

check_serial(output)
```

Why is the comparison failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the command contains a trailing newline. You should remove that using [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd1, shell=True).strip()
```